# SharePoint 2007 - Field Filters Not Working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

The filters for SharePoint 2007 fields (the drop down arrows you can click and then filter for a specific item) aren't working. Additionally, where you have the ability to export into datasheet under actions doesn't work now either.

I'm not sure what changed as this is an end user's machine, but I haven't been able to figure out the fix. Perhaps it is an issue with it not running ActiveX? I have no idea.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have there been any customisations to the masterpage or any other page, like custom Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem limited to the end user's machine only?  (Try clearing out the browser cache and restarting the browser).

Are there script errors on the page when you try and sort the columns?  As @JamesLove suggests, this may be a problem with customisations.

Is the problem specific to a particular list, web, site collection or web application?